# css hack for sobou browser

Tags: html, css

How can i write my css code for Sogou browser, as i have used css hack for safari browser which in results affecting the position of my element .Below is the css code for safari:

```
        @media screen and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 0)
          .search-box-left input[type='image'] {
              top: 15px;
        }
```

what i want for Sogou browser is :

```
         .search-box-left input[type='image'] {
           top: 25px;
          }
```

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sogou#Sogou_browser

So Please Suggest.

Comment: Does the Sogou browser have issues that you are trying to overcome with this hack? Or are you trying to single out the Sogou browser for another reason?

Comment: Since Sogou uses a mixture of Webkit and Trident, it's no wonder it fails in even basic CSS stuff.

Comment: @connexo I got rather the impression that the browser could use either the trident, or the webkit engine. Not both at the same time, or some creepy hybrid!

Comment: @Mr Lister I want css code which  only  run for sogou browser

Comment: this works by adding css on run time .